# Why doesn't my sahi controller come up?

Tags: controller, sahi

I just installed Sahi and I can't seem to figure out why I am not able to bring up the controller. I tried with Alt and double click. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The controller will only come up if the web page has been modified by the Sahi proxy.

Try the following:

```
Refresh the browser and check
Force Reload (override cache),
Firefox: Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R Internet Explorer: Ctrl + F5
```

OR

```
Clear the browser cache manually and reload.

Make sure popup blockers are turned off.

If you are surfing the intranet on IE:
Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings. There, make sure that “Bypass proxy for local addresses” is unchecked.

If you are surfing an https site, make sure that the proxy is configured for SSL/HTTPS on your browser. Also have a look at https/ssl sites do not work properly

If using Internet Explorer 7 (or higher), surfing to http://localhost:port and http://127.0.0.1:port may bypass Sahi. Try using your machine name instead of localhost.
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. (I believe after 2 days right after posting it)

Answer (score 2):

Did not work for me either, despite working proxy (sahi's javascript beeing injected into pages). Probably that's because <kbd>alt</kbd>+drag is bond to moving windows in my windows manager.

You can try opening sahi controller window manually. Enter this into address bar:

```
javascript:window._sahi?window._sahi.openWin():alert('Sashi seems to be absent.');
```

That will display error message, if proxy is not working.